# How to send uint8 and uint32 data with android ble interface as structure

Tags: java, android, struct, types, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need send following structure with Android ble class but unfortunately java does not support struct type and I have to convert my structer to class. Actually I can create a class like structure but my big issue is, java also does not support uint8 and uint32 type.

I found Format_UINT32 and Format_UINT8 methods under the BluethootGattChracteristic but it wont work my code. I always send the same array to target device with following code

My standart C structure like below

```
    struct test{
    Time1 uint32;
    Time2 uint32;
    Time3 uint32;
    Time4 uint32;
    Time5 uint32;
    Time6 uint32;
    Speed uint8;
    Speed2 uint8;
    Speed3 uint8;
    }
```

I create same types in java like below

```
long Time1= 4000000000L;
long Time2= 1500L;
long Time3= 0L;
long Time4= 0L;
long Time5= 0L;
long Time6= 0L;
int speed = 01;
int speed2 = 02;
int speed3 = 04;
```

and than I tried to send this data with ble write method like this;

```
Time1= BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT32;
Time2= BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT32;
Time3= BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT32;
Time4= BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT32;
Time5= BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT32;
Time6= BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT32;
speed= BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8;
speed2= BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8;
speed3= BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8;

ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(27);

buffer.put((byte)Time1);
buffer.put((byte)Time2);
buffer.put((byte)Time3);
buffer.put((byte)Time4);
buffer.put((byte)Time5);
buffer.put((byte)Time6);
buffer.put((byte)speed);
buffer.put((byte)speed2);
buffer.put((byte)speed3);
buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
charac.setValue(buffer.array());
```

somehow this code send data array like 0x1414141411111110000 … but this is totaly wrong.

How can solve this problem? or How can I create a class like my structure above?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're code has some good elements but then you send just the constant values for `BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT32` and no real data. You don't need `BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT32`.

So let's take a simple class to hold the data:

```
class Payload {
    int time1;
    int time2;
    int time3;
    int time4;
    int time5;
    int time6;
    byte speed1;
    byte speed2;
    byte speed3;

}
```

You then create a byte array from it using a `ByteBuffer`:

```
byte[] createBytes(Payload payload) {
    ByteByffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(28).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

    buffer.putInt(payload.time1);
    buffer.putInt(payload.time2);
    buffer.putInt(payload.time3);
    buffer.putInt(payload.time4);
    buffer.putInt(payload.time5);
    buffer.putInt(payload.time6);
    buffer.putByte(payload.speed1);
    buffer.putByte(payload.speed2);
    buffer.putByte(payload.speed3);
    buffer.putByte(0);
    return buffer.array();
}
```

The additional 0 is to pad the data length to a multiple of 4, namely 28. Most likely, the C struct will be 28 bytes long.

Finally, you transmit the data:

```
byte[] data = createBytes(payload);
gattCharacteristic.setValue(data);
```

Note that the Java integer types are signed (e.g. -128 to 127 for *byte*) while your C types are unsigned (e.g. 0 to 255 for *uint8_t*). This might require some additional handling in Java.